# how to nested json to lists to dataframe code loop if key exists

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I currently breakdown nested json with a for loop. I make lists and then put into dataframe. Some have all the same keys and some do not. This is partial from 15 page nested json file.

```
idents = [item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'] for item in MyStore.resp['items']]
```

example:
{'kind': 'books#volumes', 'totalItems': 2013, 'items': [{'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'VDiuNwAACAAJ', 'etag': 'H5/AIdrbiqc', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/VDiuNwAACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Total massage', 'authors': ['Gill Tree'], 'publishedDate': '2006-10-28', 'description': "Une introduction à l'histoire du massage et à ses principes. Une reliure spirale pour faciliter la consultation de l'ouvrage. Plus de 80 techniques de massage simples, pour toutes les parties du corps. Plus de 300 photos explicatives en couleur. 14 programmes de massage : auto massage, massage du nourrisson, de la personne âgée, massage anti-stress...", 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '2744062448'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9782744062445'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 192, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'language': 'fr', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=VDiuNwAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=VDiuNwAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/Total_massage.html?hl=&id=VDiuNwAACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=VDiuNwAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': '9VEDwQEACAAJ', 'etag': '5K8u9aLludg', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/9VEDwQEACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Total Massage', 'authors': ['Jack L. Hofer'], 'publishedDate': '1976', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '044812324X'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9780448123240'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 223, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Massage'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=9VEDwQEACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=2&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=9VEDwQEACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/Total_Massage.html?hl=&id=9VEDwQEACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=9VEDwQEACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'HSy8sMP-iyoC', 'etag': '1/6PyaCgq+A', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/HSy8sMP-iyoC', 'volumeInfo': {'title': "The World's Best Massage Techniques The Complete Illustrated Guide", 'subtitle': 'Innovative Bodywork Practices From Around the Globe for Pleasure, Relaxation, and Pain Relief', 'authors': ['Victoria Stone'], 'publisher': 'Fair Winds Press', 'publishedDate': '2010-12-01', 'description': 'Massage is one of the oldest healing modalities in the world and even modern science is proving its incredible power to soothe anxiety, boost immunity, and alleviate pain. The World’s Best Massage Techniques presents the most effective massage and bodywork techniques from around the world—many of which have been used for thousands of years—to soothe stress and tension, alleviate discomfort, and give pleasure. This beautiful hands-on guide teaches you how to skillfully apply a wide variety of massage and bodywork techniques from other cultures for relaxation, stress relief, and wellness. — Swedish Massage: Kneading strokes lengthen tense muscles — Hot Stone Massage: Heated, flowing movements penetrate tight knots — Thai Yoga Massage: Assisted stretches bring the body into alignment — Reflexology: Focused pressure activates energy meridians — Lomi Lomi: Sensuous strokes calm the body and mind — Tantsu: Close, body-to-body contact creates intimacy — Polarity: Gentle rocking movements loosen muscles and joints — Shiatsu: Small compressions reduce pain and aid injury recovery Color photography and step-by-step layout make techniques understandable and immediately applicable. With The World’s Best Massage Techniques you can use the world’s most exciting bodywork techniques in your own home.', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781610593830'}, {'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '1610593839'}], 'readingModes': {'text': True, 'image': True}, 'pageCount': 256, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'averageRating': 5, 'ratingsCount': 1, 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': True, 'contentVersion': '1.8.9.0.preview.3', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=3&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': True, 'listPrice': {'amount': 24.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amount': 24.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'buyLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&rdid=book-HSy8sMP-iyoC&rdot=1&source=gbs_api', 'offers': [{'finskyOfferType': 1, 'listPrice': {'amountInMicros': 24990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amountInMicros': 24990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'giftable': True}]}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'PARTIAL', 'embeddable': True, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/The_World_s_Best_Massage_Techniques_The-sample-epub.acsm?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/The_World_s_Best_Massage_Techniques_The-sample-pdf.acsm?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=HSy8sMP-iyoC&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'SAMPLE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'This beautiful hands-on guide teaches you how to skillfully apply a wide variety of massage and bodywork techniques from other cultures for relaxation, stress relief, and wellness. — Swedish Massage: Kneading strokes lengthen tense ...'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'rbW1DwAAQBAJ', 'etag': 'xyCSUhqSio4', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/rbW1DwAAQBAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Complete Massage', 'subtitle': 'All the Techniques, Disciplines, and Skills you need to Massage for Wellness', 'authors': ["Neal's Yard Remedies"], 'publisher': 'Penguin', 'publishedDate': '2019-09-03', 'description': "Want to really understand the health and wellness benefits of massage? Interested in practicing massage at home or considering taking a course? Let this be your guide on everything from effleurage to epineuria. Annotated anatomy and physiology illustrations show you how different levels of pressure work the muscles, and the profound effect massage can have on the nervous system and on cardio and lymphatic health. Learn how to prepare physically and mentally, and get the lowdown on oils and massage beds, diffusers and candles. And if you're receiving a massage, find out why drinking water before and after is important and how focusing on breathing enhances muscle relaxation. All the core strokes and massage techniques that form the foundation of massage practice are shown photographically with detailed annotations and integrated arrows showing the direction and application of pressure. Familiarize yourself with the key disciplines, from Swedish to shiatsu, reflexology and hot stone therapy. Access over 30 bespoke massage sequences, tailored to treat specific complaints and special client groups, such as pregnant women, babies, and those recovering from surgery. Become an expert in the simple but profoundly effective power of touch and share its miraculous health benefits.", 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781465498915'}, {'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '1465498915'}], 'readingModes': {'text': True, 'image': True}, 'pageCount': 248, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': '1.5.4.0.preview.3', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=4&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': True, 'listPrice': {'amount': 12.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amount': 12.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'buyLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&rdid=book-rbW1DwAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_api', 'offers': [{'finskyOfferType': 1, 'listPrice': {'amountInMicros': 12990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amountInMicros': 12990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'giftable': True}]}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'PARTIAL', 'embeddable': True, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/Complete_Massage-sample-epub.acsm?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/Complete_Massage-sample-pdf.acsm?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=rbW1DwAAQBAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'SAMPLE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'Want to really understand the health and wellness benefits of massage? Interested in practicing massage at home or considering taking a course? Let this be your guide on everything from effleurage to epineuria.'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'DIHtDQAAQBAJ', 'etag': '938m1rhI+Kg', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/DIHtDQAAQBAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'The Complete Guide to Massage', 'subtitle': 'A Step-by-Step Guide to Achieving the Health and Relaxation Benefits of Massage', 'authors': ['Mary Biancalana'], 'publisher': 'Simon and Schuster', 'publishedDate': '2015-12-04', 'description': "Discover the healing power of massage therapy! With The Complete Guide to Massage, you can use the power of touch to soothe aches and wash away worries. Each page guides you through the time-honored practice with step-by-step instructions and photographs for massaging yourself and others. You'll learn the different strokes and movements within a massage as well as techniques for popular methods, including prenatal massage, Swedish massage, and trigger point therapy. Whether you're looking to relieve muscle tension, alleviate pain, or simply de-stress, The Complete Guide to Massage will help you uncover a whole new world of healing and relaxation.", 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781440594021'}, {'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '1440594023'}], 'readingModes': {'text': True, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 256, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': True, 'contentVersion': '1.3.2.0.preview.2', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=5&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': True, 'listPrice': {'amount': 14.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amount': 14.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'buyLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&rdid=book-DIHtDQAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_api', 'offers': [{'finskyOfferType': 1, 'listPrice': {'amountInMicros': 14990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amountInMicros': 14990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'giftable': True}]}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'PARTIAL', 'embeddable': True, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY', 'epub': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/The_Complete_Guide_to_Massage-sample-epub.acsm?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=DIHtDQAAQBAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'SAMPLE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'Discover the healing power of massage therapy! With The Complete Guide to Massage, you can use the power of touch to soothe aches and wash away worries.'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'l1tCMQAACAAJ', 'etag': 'gPZaa/p2E54', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/l1tCMQAACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'The Art of Massage', 'authors': ['A. Creighton Hale'], 'publishedDate': '1904', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'OTHER', 'identifier': 'OCLC:3286942'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 144, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Massage'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=l1tCMQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=6&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=l1tCMQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Art_of_Massage.html?hl=&id=l1tCMQAACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=l1tCMQAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'dzn_QQAACAAJ', 'etag': 'GHDTfS0OkgA', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/dzn_QQAACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'The Complete Body Massage Course', 'subtitle': 'An Introduction to the Most Popular Massage Therapies', 'authors': ['Nicola Stewart'], 'publisher': 'Collins & Brown', 'publishedDate': '2010-03-01', 'description': "What’s the best massage for you? Do you just want a quick, relaxing massage, or do you have a specific condition, and need to know which massage therapy will heal it most effectively? Whatever you’re looking for, 'The Complete Body Massage Course' is sure to have it. The book features massage treatments to promote general wellbeing and help a wide range of everyday ailments and conditions. The first part of the book details the basics – what to wear, how to set up your work space and oils and lubricants. This is followed by the main part of the book where you will find detailed instructions of 15 of the most popular massage therapies - including Swedish, Thai, Shiatsu and Indian Head Massage. Each one has a full introduction giving the history and the benefits of the therapy and then there are step-by-step colour photographs, enabling the beginner to learn the principles each one. For those who wish to learn more and investigate further the third part offers a range of other therapies in more concise detail. The book ends with a fully cross-referenced symptoms index so readers who wish to try a massage that's ideal for a specific condition or ailment, can find the right massage with the minimum of fuss. 'The Complete Body Massage Course' is the ideal resource book for all those interested in being introduced to the massage techniques available to improve their mental and physical wellbeing.", 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '1843405709'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781843405702'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 0, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=dzn_QQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=dzn_QQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=dzn_QQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=7&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=dzn_QQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Complete_Body_Massage_Course.html?hl=&id=dzn_QQAACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=dzn_QQAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'Whatever you’re looking for, 'The Complete Body Massage Course' is sure to have it. The book features massage treatments to promote general wellbeing and help a wide range of everyday ailments and conditions.'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': '_jodAwAAQBAJ', 'etag': 'yO9gaI0msVw', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/_jodAwAAQBAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Encyclopedia of Thai Massage', 'subtitle': 'A Complete Guide to Traditional Thai Massage Therapy and Acupressure', 'authors': ['C. Pierce Salguero', 'David Roylance'], 'publisher': 'Simon and Schuster', 'publishedDate': '2011-12-01', 'description': 'Drawing from Thai history, cultural studies, Buddhist religion, and yogic practices, as well as a modern understanding of anatomy and physiology, this guidebook bridges the gap between theory and practice while presenting bodywork as it is understood in Thailand—as a therapeutic medical science. Presenting detailed analysis of each step in a Thai massage routine, the history, spiritual traditions, and ethical codes are offered in an engaging, informal style. Numerous photographs and diagrams illustrate the variety of techniques used, and examples of routines for treating specific disorders are discussed. Updated with new layout, photos, and expanded text, this exhaustive handbook is complete with a section on the main energy meridians and diagrams of acupressure points, making it the perfect tool to accompany anyone studying this popular healing modality.', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781844093939'}, {'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '184409393X'}], 'readingModes': {'text': True, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 288, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': True, 'contentVersion': '1.9.9.0.preview.2', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=8&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': True, 'listPrice': {'amount': 17.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amount': 17.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'buyLink': 'https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&rdid=book-_jodAwAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_api', 'offers': [{'finskyOfferType': 1, 'listPrice': {'amountInMicros': 17990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'retailPrice': {'amountInMicros': 17990000, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'giftable': True}]}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'PARTIAL', 'embeddable': True, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY', 'epub': {'isAvailable': True, 'acsTokenLink': 'http://books.google.com/books/download/Encyclopedia_of_Thai_Massage-sample-epub.acsm?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api'}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=_jodAwAAQBAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'SAMPLE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'Updated with new layout, photos, and expanded text, this exhaustive handbook is complete with a section on the main energy meridians and diagrams of acupressure points, making it the perfect tool to accompany anyone studying this popular ...'}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'P4oLGQAACAAJ', 'etag': 'yyuDvL/M70w', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/P4oLGQAACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Massage for Total Well-Being', 'subtitle': 'Massage and Meditation for the Seven Centers of Health', 'authors': ['Anne Kent Rush'], 'publisher': 'Rizzoli International Publications', 'publishedDate': '2007-11-13', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '0789317028'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9780789317025'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 143, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Health & Fitness'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=P4oLGQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=P4oLGQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=P4oLGQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=9&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=P4oLGQAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/Massage_for_Total_Well_Being.html?hl=&id=P4oLGQAACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=P4oLGQAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}}, {'kind': 'books#volume', 'id': 'meSCRAAACAAJ', 'etag': 'igYgS9EGvs8', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/meSCRAAACAAJ', 'volumeInfo': {'title': 'Total Massage', 'subtitle': 'Step-by-step Massage Techniques to Relax Body and Mind', 'authors': ['Karen Smith'], 'publisher': 'Watkins Publishing', 'publishedDate': '2011', 'description': 'A complete introduction to massage techniques, showing how to use massage to target areas of particular tension in the body.', 'industryIdentifiers': [{'type': 'ISBN_10', 'identifier': '1907486372'}, {'type': 'ISBN_13', 'identifier': '9781907486371'}], 'readingModes': {'text': False, 'image': False}, 'pageCount': 0, 'printType': 'BOOK', 'categories': ['Massage'], 'maturityRating': 'NOT_MATURE', 'allowAnonLogging': False, 'contentVersion': 'preview-1.0.0', 'panelizationSummary': {'containsEpubBubbles': False, 'containsImageBubbles': False}, 'imageLinks': {'smallThumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=meSCRAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api', 'thumbnail': 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=meSCRAAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}, 'language': 'en', 'previewLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=meSCRAAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&cd=10&source=gbs_api', 'infoLink': 'http://books.google.com/books?id=meSCRAAACAAJ&dq=title:Total+Massage&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'canonicalVolumeLink': 'https://books.google.com/books/about/Total_Massage.html?hl=&id=meSCRAAACAAJ'}, 'saleInfo': {'country': 'US', 'saleability': 'NOT_FOR_SALE', 'isEbook': False}, 'accessInfo': {'country': 'US', 'viewability': 'NO_PAGES', 'embeddable': False, 'publicDomain': False, 'textToSpeechPermission': 'ALLOWED', 'epub': {'isAvailable': False}, 'pdf': {'isAvailable': False}, 'webReaderLink': 'http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=meSCRAAACAAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api', 'accessViewStatus': 'NONE', 'quoteSharingAllowed': False}, 'searchInfo': {'textSnippet': 'A complete introduction to massage techniques, showing how to use massage to target areas of particular tension in the body.'}}]}

Two parts are not evident to me.

1. Can I check for if key exists, in this format of code.
2. If two parts of key exist, can I breakdown into both parts, even if order of two parts is different.

I changed the json file since someone thinks it is not complete enough to understand what is being asked.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your JSON.  First, there is no top level list for the items.  Then top level items aren't dicts, but a list.  Even so, there is no 'volumeInfo' reference at all.  And finally 'industryIdentifiers' is not a key in a dictionary, but just the first entry in a list.

Comment: It will be a lot easier to deal with these if each item were mapped to something that looked more like `{'volumeInfo': {'industryIdentifiers': {'ISBN_13': '9781465498915', 'ISBN_10': '1465498915'}, 'OTHER': []}}`.  (I made 'OTHER' and array with the assumption that with such a "type" there might be multiple for some items.)  This solves the order problem, and lets you reference the entries in a way that makes your code work.